# @Transactional noRollBackFor for subClasses

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Let's say i've got a method like that:

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = ImportException.class, noRollbackFor = MultipleImportException.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public ProcessImport doImport(File file) throws ImportException, RetryLaterException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        return doImport(file, in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ImportException(e);
    }
}
```

`ImportException` is extending `Exception` and has some more functionality besides that, the `MultipleImportException` is extending `ImportException`. So my Question: Is there no possibility to use a subClass for noRollBack-Policy?